# Same code, different results on different machines regarding UTF8 characters

Tags: perl, utf-8

I have this code:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use utf8;
use HTML::Entities;
use feature 'say';

binmode STDOUT, ':encoding(utf-8)';

my $t1 = "&#x010c;esk&aacute; Spo&#x0159;itelna - Q3 2014";
my $t2 =  "&#268;esk&aacute; Spo&#345;itelna - Q3 2014";

say decode_entities($t1);
say decode_entities($t2);
```

which, when executed on my dev machine, outputs:

```
Česká Spořitelna - Q3 2014
Česká Spořitelna - Q3 2014
```

and when executed on the UAT machine (Aser Acceptance Test), outputs:

```
ÄeskÃ¡ SpoÅitelna - Q3 2014
ÄeskÃ¡ SpoÅitelna - Q3 2014
```

Now, on both machines, when I run `perl -v` we have *This is perl 5, version 16, subversion 3 (v5.16.3) built for x86_64-linux-thread-multi-ld*

and the version of `HTML::Entities` is the same on both machines:

```
    Installed: 3.69
    CPAN:      3.69  up to date
```

My dev machine runs `CentOS release 5.8 (Final)` and the UAT machine runs `Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 5.8 (Tikanga)`

**EDIT** (regarding the output of the `locale` command)
The output of it is the same on both machines:

```
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
```

**UPDATE**:

I posted the link to this question on the [perl developers](https://www.facebook.com/groups/100858186649890/) group on facebook and got some really useful ideas from there: *compare the output bytes on the two systems*. If they're identical, it's a display issue. And they are. Now, **there is more than one way to do it**:

1)

```
say join ':', map { ord } split //, decode_entities($t1);
say join ':', map { ord } split //, decode_entities($t2);
```

which displays `268:101:115:107:225:32:83:112:111:345:105:116:101:108:110:97:32:45:32:81:51:32:50:48:49:52` on both systems, so, the bytes are the same

2) print `$t1` and `$t2` output to a file on each system, then run a `hexdump -C` against those files and compare the output. This method also showed that the content of the files is the same

**Conclusion**

It is a display problem - the console (putty) does not display the characters properly. 
 We have this problem when we add those characters in the DB and I thought I managed to isolate it with the above code. Your answers (and some from fb) helped me find out that the `decode_entities()` works as expected, and our problem lies somewhere else (most probably at the mysql table charset or the mysql connection).

Comment: Check the output of `locale` command on both machines.

Comment: The terminal expects something other than UTF-8, but you are outputting UTF-8. Adjust the encoding the terminal expects or adjust the encoding used so they match.

Comment: How are you connecting to these machines?  Do you use the same terminal program for both?  Does it have settings which are specific to each host?

Comment: check how the shell accepts utf8 i/o. e.g. try `touch ČeskáKočka` and `ls`. Using bash? Try set `set convert-meta off;set input-meta on;set output-meta on`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The encoding that the command terminals expect is different. If you want to print UTF-8 you must set both terminals to expect UTF-8 with, for instance for Romanian

```
LANG=ro_RO.UTF-8
```

as well as setting `STDOUT` to *encode* the output that way in your Perl with, for example

```
binmode STDOUT, ':encoding(utf-8)'
```

---

**Update**

I can explain what is happening, although quite *why* it's that way I'm not sure.

Take the first character of the string: `"\x{010C}"` which is a capital C caron. That is being encoded by Perl as the two-octet code `"\x{C4}\x{8C}"` and sent to the terminal, which, on your development machine, is decoding it and displaying it correctly.

However, on your test machine the terminal is decoding the first octet of the encoded character - `C4` - as if it were ISO-8859-1,  a capital A umlaut. The second octet - `8C` - is ignored because it's an invalid character in that encoding.

So you need to change the code page your terminal is using. The way to do that is by setting `LANG` as I described, but I can't explain why it isn't working if your *locale* is set up correctly.

Comment: I've updated the question with your suggestion - do you have any other thoughts I should try on this?

Comment: Your terminal is almost certainly set to ISO-8859-1. See my update. See what `LANG` is set to using `echo $LANG`

Comment: the problem appears when we add those characters in the DB. I thought I managed to isolate it with the above code. Your answers (and some from fb) helped me find out that the `decode_entities()` worked as expected, and the problem was (presumably) related to the console (putty)

Comment: @TudorConstantin: Ah you didn't tell us about PuTTY!. It ignores the setting of `LANG` as it should (after all, you're not running PuTTY on the remote host). But as soon as it starts up you see `PuTTY Configuration` where, if you choose Window` / `Translation`, you can select `UTF-8`, and the problem is solved. I hope you have learned to explain your questions better? No one could have guessed that you weren't sat at a terminal *directly connected* to the two systems that you describe. Please write a solution of your own and accept it to mark your question as being resolved.

Comment: well, as I said, I wasn't interested in having the chars *displayed* correctly. Your answers **helped** me to isolate the problem, so I accept your answer. I updated the question with the details for further references :)

Comment: @TudorConstantin: I have put several hours into formulating a helpful response to your question. Please don't just run away with the solution now that you have one. I think it will take you rather less than an hour to put together an account of the full solution so that our effort is useful to those who have a similar issue and happen upon your question. Or were you counting on getting consultancy for no effort?

Comment: have you seen that I updated the question to add all the extra info, the judgments I made and the conclusions I reached following the interactions with you and on fb? what do you think I have to add/do more? debug the putty connection settings to make sure they're the same to those machines?

Comment: Ok, coming back to `putty`. As you guys suggested, `putty` was the culprit. It had the *Remote character set* set to `ISO-8859-1:1998 (Latin-1, West Europe)` (I don't know who or how set that because I never configure that setting). When I change the setting to UTF8, the strings are displayed correctly